# How can i draw radial gradient background with end transparent?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want draw radial gradient background with end transparent. How can i?
two gradient togather!
Is it possible?

Thanks

[My Gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4MNf.jpg)

Comment: use transparent "end" color

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do research, try something. If the code doesn't work then and you are stuck post it on SO.

Comment: @pskink I want draw radial gradient background with end transparen, realy two gradient togather!

Comment: what two gradient? what you mean?

Comment: you can use at least 3 colors in your gradient: `<gradient
  android:startColor="#FF0000"
  android:endColor="#00FF00"
  android:centerColor="#0000FF">
 </gradient>` Use the `endColor` as transparent, and you will get it transparent in the end

Comment: @pskink Added Gradient Image

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="@color/background_light_grey"
          android:endColor="@color/transparent"
          android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  create a drawable resource in res/try and use use transparent color in `android:endColor="#80000000"` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="250"
                android:startColor="#ff2d9a59"
                android:centerColor="#ff42959a"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"// add here transparent color
            />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I want draw circular gradient background with end transparen, realy two gradient togather!

Comment: can u exaplin in brief of provide picture

Comment: Sample Gradient image Added

Comment: @AHMADMOHAMMADI than try my ans and let me know the output

Comment: Did you see the added image?

Comment: @AHMADMOHAMMADI yes i saw that image

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: you can try that

Comment: how can i? your sample is one linear gradient

Comment: that's only radial gradient, I want draw a linear gradient  border over  radial gradient (background).